# laravel 4 route to controller with wildcard methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the latest Laravel4 and currently testing routes and controllers. I want to define a route to a controller (TestController) which takes care of possible methods and all other uri-segments ...

```
Route::controller('/test', 'TestController');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "index";
    }

    public function test()
    {
        echo "test";
    }

    public function missingMethod($parameters)
    {
         echo "missing method";
    }

}
```

But this dont work, always get:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

when calling /test/test or /test/index

Also the missingMethod dont work ... ?

Comment: Btw: you shouldn' t handle NotFounds on your self. There is a 404 event in Laravel already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using RESTful controller methods.

```
// In routes.php
Route::controller('test', 'TestController');
```

Then in your controller... ./TestController.php

```
<?php

class TestController extends \BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return 'Hello World.';
    }

    public function getPage()
    {
        return "Hello World I'm another page";
    }
}
```

Comment: This dont work for me, dont know why ... if I navigate to domain.com/test I get "ErrorException Undefined offset: 1"

Comment: I've fixed it. There was a typo when declaring the route. It was Route::get instead of Route::controller [http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)